# vibrator в android

Tags: android

есть следующий код:

```
  Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
  long[] pattern = {0,  4000, 2000, 4000, 2000, 4000, 2000};
  v.vibrate(pattern, -1);
```

все компилируется без проблем, но при запуске на устройстве все падает с ошибкой на вызове `v.vibrate`. код взят из примера. подскажите пожалуйста, что здесь не так?

Comment: Приведите `stackTrace` ошибки из `logCat`

Comment: какое устройство? в устройстве есть вибратор? покажите что за ошибку он дает

Comment: Оч. секси вопрос )))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

вы добавили?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

если нет, добавьте в `AndroidManifest.xml` эту строку

Comment: Я уверен на 99%, что нет, т.к. все остальное верно.

Comment: Да, разумеется это в  манифесте есть.

Comment: вы включили `import android.os.Vibrator;` ?

Comment: Еще раз перепроверил. Действительно, в манифесте прошляпил одну букву (написал не android-name, a andrid-name). Но эта гадина не выдала ошибки ни при компиляции, ни при проверке синтаксиса, это и смутило. Большое спасибо

Comment: почему минус ? интересно